# Where is Application Insights injecting HttpContext into IHttpContextAccessor.Request?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, unity-container, azure-application-insights

I've found myself in an interesting position.  I currently use the latest Unity container, I'm on asp.net core 2.2, and I use application insights.  As such, I have configured DI in my web app to use unity instead of the out of the box DI provider in core.  I also use Application Insights and use the IWebHostBuilder.UseApplicationInsights extension to spin up AI for my app.

With all this in mind, I have a piece of code whose constructor takes in IHttpContextAccessor so I can access the HttpContext.  It was working great.  Then, I had another small app that I was trying to reuse the functionality, and the HttpContext was null coming from IHttpContextAccessor.  With a bunch of guess, test, revise, I found that IWebHostBuilder.UseApplicationInsights seems to initialize that Request property (HttpContext) on IHttpContextAccessor.  If I commented out that AI extension, I would get null; uncomment it, it worked.

I've started to look through the AI code to figure out what exactly they're doing, but honestly, with all the dependencies and pipelines and all that, it's a pretty daunting task.  I was hoping someone could point out where/how AI is doing this so my code doesn't NEED AI in order to work.  All help would be incredibly awesome.

Comment: Just add the accessor yourself at startup mappnig `IHttpContextAccessor` to `HttpContextAccessor`

Comment: Yes, I did this

Answer (score 0):

Use AddHttpContextAccessor extension to add it to DI. HttpContextAccessor is not added by default due to performance impact.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Answer (score 0):

After some struggle, and hoping this post would enlighten me on the AI ask, I found that I didn't need to replicate the AI mechanism, if there's even one at all.

Originally, I was accessing the IHttpContextAccessor via code in the view (Razor).  I have an abstract factory pattern I was using to instantiate IHttpContextAccessor via Unity (this pattern came over from my .Net Frame work days).  Once I moved that code back to the controller and used proper .net core DI to get the dependency via the constructor, everything started working.

There must be something there I'm missing, but I have the code working so I'm happy.  If someone could shed light on why one way works vs the other, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

When you enable application insights by calling .UseApplicationInsights(), it adds HttpContextAccessor. There are many components in ApplicationInsights which require HttpContextAccessor injected to it. eg: ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer.

This is the exact line where this is occuring:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/Extensions/ApplicationInsightsExtensions.cs#L137